About symbols tag
Should we use symbols for all questions related with any symbol information?
I think it is too broad for all symbol related operations. It can be used for analysing executable file types, operating systems or understanding linker, loader and compiler mechanisms. 

I don't quite understand the question. Is your issue that the tag is improperly added to some questions, or that it's too broad, or too narrow?

Thanks for comment, i think it is too broad using symbols tag for all of these and makes it difficult for finding relative questions. Maybe using tags like kernel-symbols, relocation can define question better?

Yes, in theory we could add more fine-grained tags but I don't think there are so many questions on the site yet that such distinction is necessary.
